# How to secure packets from android to http server

Tags: android, http, security, https, sniffing

Is there any way to secure sending of data from my android application to `http` server? I have read articles that changing `http` to `https` will make it easier and secured. If I get to successfully change it to `https`, is still there not enough security for data-sniffing or will that be enough for security??

Answer (score 1):

https means there will be TLS tunnel which means all the data inside http will be encrypted.
Someone can always sniff the traffic but with https the traffic will be encrypted, so they will not be able to see the data, unless they can break the encryption.

There are also different versions of TLS protocol and cipher suits. If you switch to https check if you are using proper ones, not some outdated that can be broken easily.

As to if this will be enough security, it depends on the project/ your company standards for security and compliance.

Comment: Okay thank you! was thinking of using own encryption but it can still be seen as plain text somehow. thanks a lot!

Comment: making up your own encryption is a bad idea for multiple reasons.Using existing libraries like openssl and industry standards will save you time and will be safer in the long run. Also you can do certificate pinning in your application to make sure that there will bee no issues even if someone manages to get a rouge valid certificate.